# Driver Java Animal Reserve

Tags: java

Unsure of where my code is failing, and where I should be going next with it. I need a fully functional loop menu, that seems to work so far, in which I am able to do the options the menu displays. This includes adding to lists and checking lists. I also am having an issue in which the dog list is not displaying the list of dogs by their name or information, but rather their space. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        // Complete intakeNewMonkey
    //Instantiate and add the new monkey to the appropriate list
        // For the project submission you must also  validate the input
    // to make sure the monkey doesn't already exist and the species type is allowed
        public static void intakeNewMonkey(Scanner scanner) {
            System.out.println("What is the new monkey's name?");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            for (Monkey monkey: monkeyList) {
                if(monkey.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    System.out.println("\n\nThis monkey is already in our system.\n\n");
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's tail length?");
            String tailLength = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's gender?");
            String gender = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's age?");
            String age = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's weight?");
            String weight = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's acquisition date?");
            String acquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's acquisition country?");
            String acquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's training status?");
            String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("Is the monkey reserved? <enter true or false>");
            boolean reservedBoolean = scanner.nextBoolean();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's service country?");
            String serviceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's body length?");
            String bodyLength = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's height?");
            String height = scanner.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's species?");
            String species = scanner.nextLine();
            
            
            
            

        }

        // Complete reserveAnimal
        // You will need to find the animal by animal type and in service country
        public static void reserveAnimal(Scanner scanner) {
            System.out.println("Enter animal type");
            String type = scanner.nextLine();

            if (type.equals("Monkey") || type.equals("monkey")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < monkeyList.size(); i++) {
                    if (!monkeyList.get(i).getReserved());
                    System.out.println(monkeyList.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println("Enter name: ");
                String name = scanner.nextLine();
                for (Monkey obj: monkeyList) {

                    if (obj.name.equals(name)) {
                        obj.reserved = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Monkey not found in list");
            }
            if (type.equals("Dog") || type.equals("dog")) {
                for (int i = 0; i < dogList.size(); i++) {
                    if (dogList.get(i).getReserved())
                        System.out.println(dogList.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println("Enter name: ");
                String name = scanner.nextLine();
                for (Dog obj: dogList) {
                    if (obj.name.equals(name)) {
                        obj.reserved = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Dog not found in list");
            }
                }
         


        // Complete printAnimals
        // Include the animal name, status, acquisition country and if the animal is reserved.
    // Remember that this method connects to three different menu items.
        // The printAnimals() method has three different outputs
        // based on the listType parameter
        // dog - prints the list of dogs
        // monkey - prints the list of monkeys
        // available - prints a combined list of all animals that are
        // fully trained ("in service") but not reserved 
    // Remember that you only have to fully implement ONE of these lists. 
    // The other lists can have a print statement saying "This option needs to be implemented".
    // To score "exemplary" you must correctly implement the "available" list.
        public static void printAnimals() {
            System.out.println("The method printAnimals needs to be implemented");

        }
```

Comment: Does your Dog class have `toString()` method?

Comment: @Goion It does not

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: You need to write a toString method if you want print dog name and information you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `toString()` class provided by the `Object` class. You can do this by writing something like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return "Name: " + this.name + ". Gender " + this.gender "." // and so on
}
```